# how to add a buy transaction using bitcoin @ cryptocompare.com

Tags: tracking

I'm using cryptocompare.com to track my bitcoins and altcoins.

I've purchased some altcoins, and added these altcoins to my cryptocompare.com portfolio, and ensuring I entered the amount per unit in bitcoin, but I am unsure if this debits my total portfolio by the amount of bitcoin required to pay for the transaction.

It seems I have too much bitcoin in my portfolio @ cryptocompare.com, which doesn't reflect my purchase of altcoins using some of my bitcoin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using cryptocompare.com to track my crypto investments. However, it turns out that they do not have a functionality where the currency you entered to buy another currency gets auto-debited from your portfolio. You'll have to manually select that currency and enter the sale. I know that's not ideal. Hope the developers correct this soon.